# Pandas table join and dedupe deciding which row to keep

Tags: python, pandas, join, duplicates

I am trying to inner join and dedupe two tables while using a more complicated method of deciding which rows to keep after deduping than keep first or keep last.

Table A contains distinct IDs, and Age.
Table B contains multiple duplicated ID numbers, Ages, and data.
Only one row in Table B is correct so I want to keep only this row. The correct row is the one where the two Ages are most similar, but I also know that the correct Table B Ages are always lower than or equal to Table A Ages.

**Table A**

```
|ID  |Age|
|----|---|
|1234| 45|
```

**Table B**

```
|ID  |Age|data |
|----|---|-----|
|1234| 43|dataX|
|1234| 46|dataY|
|1234| 22|dataZ|
```

What I want is:

**Joined Table**

```
|ID  |Age_A|Age_B|data |  
|----|-----|-----|-----|  
|1234|   45|   43|dataX|
```

How can I achieve this in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) and `merge`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2.sort_values(['Age']),on='Age',by='ID').merge(df2[['Age','data']],on='data')
Out[686]: 
     ID  Age_x   data  Age_y
0  1234     45  dataX     43
```

Also we can get rid of the 2nd `merge`

```
df2['Age_B']=df2.Age
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2.sort_values(['Age']),on='Age',by='ID')
Out[688]: 
     ID  Age   data  Age_B
0  1234   45  dataX     43
```